# Global search and page search, stop search item showing in global when in page

Tags: javascript, search, search-results

I have a global search and a page search for a site in my site collection. When I search with page search the item I search also appears in the global search box when on the search results page

Is there anyway of stopping the search item showing up in the global search box when searching on a page search.

Comment: What do you mean with "Showing in the global search box"? If you search in a list views search box, the query text will not be visible in the global search box. Are you having two search boxes with different scopes on the same page?

Comment: Say if I searched hello in the page search. It will go to the page search result page but the word hello will be in the global search box

Comment: the global seach webpart is in the master page and the page search is in a pagelayout

Comment: They are really the same control, filling the text with the text in the `k=` query string parameter if it is present. They only vary in what scope is set as default